# Check if all values in a list are bigger than certain number x and smaller than y?

Tags: python

```
def fun_lst(lst, a, b):
    if min(lst)<b and max(lst)>a: 
        return True
    return False
```

How do I check if the values in the list are bigger than `a` and smaller than `b`? I tried the above, but in this example: `fun_lst([-1, 3.5, 6], -2.4, 0)`the function returns `True` and it supposed to return `False`.

Comment: `min([-1, 3.5, 6])` is `-1` and `max([-1, 3.5, 6])` is `6`, so it's normal that it returns `True` given that `-1 < 0` and `6 > -2.4`.

Comment: Here, `min(lst)` is the smallest value, -1. You check that this is less than `b`, which is 0, and it is. Similarly `max(lst)` is the largest value, 6, which you check to see if it's greater than `a`, which is -1, and again we find 6 > -1.

Comment: switch max and min in your if statement:  if max(lst)<b and min(lst)>a

Comment: Also, this isn't your main issue, but it's probably better to iterate through the list once instead of twice, and check each element, as in the answers below.

Comment: @DanielH, If your inputs are in-memory, e.g. lists, that's not necessarily the case. Two-pass can be faster when since `min` and `max` are implemented in C.

Comment: @jpp Yeah, fair

Answer (score 4):

### Do this:

```
def fun_lst(lst, a, b):
    if min(lst) > a and max(lst) < b:
        return True
    return False

print(fun_lst([-1, 3.5, 6], -2.4, 0) )
```

Output:

```
False
```

- Doing `min(lst) > a` ensures every element is **bigger** than a.
- Doing `max(lst) < b` ensures every element is **smaller** than b.

### Alternate solution:

```
def fun_lst(lst, a, b):
    return all(a < elem < b for elem in lst)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one liner if you like

```
all([num < b and num > a for num in lst])
```

Comment: You can omit the `[]` too for more efficiency.

Comment: It's not clear this will be faster than using `max` and `min` because although they iterate over the list twice (once each), they run at C speed

Comment: You can also use `a < num < b`, which you may or may not consider more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This code here will check each item in the list, if an item is found that is not greater than a and less than b then it returns false, otherwise it returns true.

```
def fun_lst(lst, a, b):
    for item in lst:
        if not a < item < b:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lower_limit = 3
upper_limit = 8
bool_output = all([i > lower_limit and i < upper_limit for i in myList])
print(bool_output)
    False

myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lower_limit = 0
upper_limit = 10
bool_output = all([i > lower_limit and i < upper_limit for i in myList])
print(bool_output)
    True
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

```
def fun_lst(lst, a, b):
    return all(n > a and n < b for n in lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a provision to use `numpy` try this

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [3]: np.array(b)
Out[3]: array([ 3,  1,  4, 66,  8,  3,  4, 56])

In [17]: b[(2<b) & (b<5)]
Out[17]: array([3, 4, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Different a method:**

```
def fun_lst(lis, x, y):
    list = [i>x and i<y for i in lis]
    return False if False in list else True
```

**It's a little easy:**

```
def fun_lst(lis, x, y):
    return x<max(lis)<y
```

**lambda version:**

```
fun_lst = lambda lis, x, y: x<max(lis)<y
```

**Outputs:**

```
fun_lst([-1, 3.5, 6], -2.4, 0) #Output: False
```